# Elasticsearch 7.x mapper [location] cannot be changed from type [geo_point] to [text]

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elasticsearch with a location field mapped as a geo_point. This is what's in the mappings tab of the index management settings.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the [geo-point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) docs on elasticsearch I should be able to send this in as a string of "lat,lon"

This is the value of a location in the json being sent to elastic

```
'location': '32.807078,-89.908972'
```

I'm getting this error message

```
RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper [location] cannot be changed from type [geo_point] to [text]')
```

UPDATE

I was able to get data flowing in but now it's coming in as text data not geo_point!

This is in my index mapping along with the other mappings

[image: This is in my mapping]

This is in the data

[image: The Data]

Even though the mapping is there the data is text and I'm unable to use it in a map chart.

SOLUTION

Along with the checked answer, also needed to do this.

Go to Home -> Manage -> Kibana -> Index Patterns

Deleted the original index pattern and created a new one and now it's being seen as geo_data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of your index mapping, it seems that you are using the elasticsearch version that is before 7.x.

I have indexed a document using the same index mapping as provided in the question (using version 6.8). Don't forget to add `_doc` (or the type you used in your index mapping) in the URL (when indexing the data)

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

**While posting a document to Elasticsearch, make sure the URL is in the format as mentioned below:**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1

{
  "location": "41.12,-71.34" 
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "_index": "65076754",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "result": "created",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 0,
  "_primary_term": 1
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

On the basis of comments below, the OP is using 7.x

**Index Mapping using 7.x**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using 7.x, I'm using the elasticsearch python library... Maybe I grabbed the wrong version... I will try with a PUT request using the requests library and see.

Comment: @Four_0h_Three if you are using 7.x, then you need to change your index mapping as well, as mapping types are removed. Please go through this, to know more about the removal of mapping types https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

Comment: @Four_0h_Three Try indexing the documents again with the index mapping I added. Please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I created a new index, added the mapping using a put request exactly as you specified above and I'm able to ingest data but it's showing as text, not geodata and I'm unable to use it in the maps graphs... There must be something dumb I'm not doing, I think I just need to step away from this for a bit and come back with a fresh mind.